# How to load selectize.js email contacts options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js like email contacts. But when I get mail list from database selectize shows undefined. When I type return value manuelly everything is fine. How can I populate it? Here is my code samples.

**Return Value:**

```
"[{"name":"Test User 1","id":"1"},{"name":"Test User 2","id":"2"}]"
```

**C#**

```
public JsonResult GetMails(){
    var list = db.Members
        .Where(x => x.IsActive == Status.Active)
        .OrderBy(x => x.FullName)
        .Select(c => new
        {
        name = c.FullName,
                id = c.Id.ToString()
        });
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.get("/mail/getmails", function (data) {
        $("#MailReceivers").selectize({
            persist: false,
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            maxItems: null,
            valueField: 'id',
            labelField: 'name',
            searchField: ['name', 'id'],
            options: JSON.stringify(data),
            create: function (input) {
                return {name: input};
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: selectize]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is first parse json and than stringfy.

```
options: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```